# Menu hover effect in Joomla Script

Tags: javascript, jquery

i need script sucha as here: http://demo.opensourcecms.com/joomla/administrator/index.php

Admin Username: admin

Admin Password: demo123

Script as menu hover effect.

Where I find this script?

Comment: You can make it yourself using CSS

Comment: no submenu only menu where is `add new article`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For icon hover effect have a look [**here**](http://jsbin.com/ihuruv/4/edit#source). It is a sample based on the link you provided.

Comment: I removed the menubar example and updated the icon example. It now contains also a text below the icon.

Answer (score 0):

Ah...I see, very nice effect. It is a JQuery animation where the border-radius is changed. Information on JQuery animations can be found in the [JQuery Docs](http://api.jquery.com/category/effects/)